# CSS Proper alignment next to image in a row

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align text to the right of an image but I can't seem to get it working, I've tried different methods of css but can't get it too work.

Edit: Also, How would I adjust this if i were to put it at the top? If I mvoe it manually then the bottom row will mess up too.

What it looks like (Default)

What I want it too look like (Only the first one, the others mess up)

Here is the css:

```
.slider__contents {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column nowrap;
      -ms-flex-flow: column nowrap;
          flex-flow: column nowrap;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}
.slider__image {
  font-size: 2.7rem;
      color: #2196F3;
}
.slider__caption {
    font-weight: 300;
    top: 95px;
    margin-left: 80px !important;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 2rem 0 1rem;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
.slider__txt {
    color: #f00;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
    max-width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 95px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Here is the html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="slider__contents">
              <img class="img-avatar1" src="/images/team/1.jpg"/>
              <h2 class="slider__caption">Matt Sowards</h2>
              <p class="slider__txt">Founder</p>
              <!-- <a href="#" target="_blank"><p class="slider__steam">Steam Profile</p></a> -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you may benefit from posting what you want it to look like. Possibly the html as well. Just at a glance though - you're not making use of the left property. left or right on those absolutely positioned items. And make sure your parent of absolutely positioned items has position relative applied.

Comment: Edited the post, should be a lot more clearer of my result I want, also the CSS has changed back to the default.

Comment: ok. well first, I would make sure .slider__contents is position:relative. from there it looks like you can clean up the text css by removing all position type settings like margins, vertical align, etc, and just go with top and left and possibly display:block. position absolute elements can make use of other things but really only those 2 are needed in this case. Try that and see if you get results. this task is a very easy one and just this little bit of info should be enough to clear it up

Comment: Can you change html or just css?

Comment: I got the same results but the top right text went down a new line.

Comment: I can change both?

Comment: is it a question or a statement?

Comment: It's confusion on why you asked that question. But yes I can change both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping your text tags into extra markup and switching to proper flex usage will net you the result you're after. Using absolute positioning is not the way to go here. See the snippet below (I have removed some code, my additions are followed by a comment):

```css
.slider__contents {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: gray;
}
.slider__image {
  font-size: 2.7rem;
  color: #2196F3;
  display: block;
  width: 4rem; /* Supposed to be the default size of the avatar */
  height: 4rem; /* Supposed to be the default size of the avatar */
  padding: 4px; /* Just to replicate your styles */
  border: 2px solid red; /* Just to replicate your styles */
  border-radius: 50%; /* Just to replicate your styles */
  background-color: white; /* Just to replicate your styles */
  overflow: hidden; /* Just to replicate your styles */
}
.slider__image img {
  width: 100%; /* Fit to container */
  border-radius: 50%; /* Round image */
}
.slider__copy { /* Added to wrap the text */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 10px; /* Avoids text sticking to the avatar */
}
.slider__caption {
  font-weight: 300;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
  margin: 0; /* Removes default margins, season to taste */
}
.slider__txt {
  color: #f00;
  max-width: 300px;
  font-size: 17px;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0; /* Removes default margins, season to taste */
  order: -1; /* Places it first in the current flex flow */
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="slider__contents">
              <div class="slider__image"><!-- Added this wrapper around your image, name as you wish -->
                <img class="img-avatar1" src="/images/team/1.jpg" alt="Avatar"/>
              </div>
              <div class="slider__copy"><!-- Added this wrapper around your text, name as you wish -->
                <h2 class="slider__caption">Matt Sowards</h2>
                <p class="slider__txt">Founder</p>
                <!-- <a href="#" target="_blank"><p class="slider__steam">Steam Profile</p></a> -->
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)
One thing though, none of the images load :?

Comment: Seems like it overflows and you've set overflow to hide

Comment: @SamuelStubbings Given I didn't have any images to insert into my snippet, I just went with a more generic solution concerning the avatars which I feel is common practice. I expect you'll adapt it to your project fairly easily.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with bootstrap cols

Example putting them in a row like so

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class=col-xs-3>
    <img src='your img'/>
    <div>
   <div class='col-xs-7'>
     <p>your text</p>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Then you could fix the positioning of the text making it appear over the img by using col-xs-pull-*. I never tested this so you may have to play around with the positioning of the columns. Just a suggestion though

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the markup you may consider this structure:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 20px;
}
.parent {
  display: flex;
  float: left;
}

.child {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.position {
  color: red;
}

.name {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="parent">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="">
    <div class="child">
      <div class="position">Developer</div>
      <div class="name">Name Nmae</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="">
    <div class="child">
      <div class="position">Developer</div>
      <div class="name">Name Nmae</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="">
    <div class="child">
      <div class="position">Developer</div>
      <div class="name">Name Nmae</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="parent">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="">
    <div class="child">
      <div class="position">Developer</div>
      <div class="name">Name Nmae</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="">
    <div class="child">
      <div class="position">Developer</div>
      <div class="name">Name Nmae</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Didn't seem to help, just made it worse :/
https://gyazo.com/f63000028e9e9bcab0a066f4a2afea39

Comment: Doesn't actually seem like my code. Are you sure you changed your html properly?

Comment: The problem is that a lot of your css interrupts mine, like `position: absolute` ect. You don't need absolute positioning if you already use flex